# How to refer to an enum from another Module in VB

Tags: vb.net, enums

I declare an enum in a Module:

```
friend Module M
  Enum E
    Elem1
    Elem2
  end Enum
end Module
```

and use it in another class:

```
Class C
  console.writeline(M.E.Elem1)  ' this works 
End Class
```

But I would like to simplify the writing of `M.E` to `MyE` so I tried:

```
Class C
  private myE as M.E  ' and variations of this using getype
  console.writeline(myE.Elem1)
end Class
```

Is there a way to do this? That is, declare `myE` as `M.E`.

I tried variations using getype but no success.

Comment: Please format your code properly, so it is readable. Regardless, an `Enum` is a type like any other, so you treat it exactly like you would any other type. That means that it shouldn't be declared inside a module in the first place. Generally speaking, I would recommend that every type be declared in its own code file, with the file named after the type. The one exception I make is for `Enums`. Because they are almost always very small and very simple, I create a code file name *Enumerations.vb* and I declare all my `Enums` there. They are never nested inside another type though.

Comment: @bernso [You can see how formatting code works with backticks if you click the [edit] link at the end of your question and see where I put backticks in for you.]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [import alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type) to simplify the name of any type or namespace. In your case:

```
Imports myE = M.E

Class C

    Public Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine(myE.Elem1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Just don't forget that `Imports` statements must be placed at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Imports is the answer. However the post from Andrew made ma think about my code structure. I placed my enum in a Module as I declared  <extension> functions associated with it.

Comment: I replaced the <Extension> by normal functions and placed the Enum as private in the class where it belongs to.
Thanks for your help